# fatal error when trying ti qmake unixODBC header files

Tags: c++, qt, unixodbc

Well i am trying to connect to mssql from rasberri pi 3 (rasbian) in qt programming and after some searched i came across unixODBC and i downloaded it and i did as they said in unixODBC.com

everything good until here, after that i tried to do as qt says in [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qodbc)
but when i am doing these lines below:

```
cd $QTDIR/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/odbc
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/unixODBC/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/local/unixODBC/lib -lodbc"
make
```

I get this error:

[image]

anybody could help what is wrong?

Comment: Have you done a search for the missing file on your entire computer?  If it is not present, you will need to install the QtSql development package.  By the way, post text, not pictures of text.

Comment: qt works fine,i will check it once more,i wanted to give better view by adding pictures